# Word order with “so” and “also”

Tags: word-order, particle

I want to say

> So, I still don’t understand this. Why did you do it that way?

I think the two most appropriate words for *so* are the German *so* and *also*. But I’m not sure about the word ordering.

> (a1) So, ich verstehe dies noch nicht. Warum hast du es in dieser Weise gemacht?
>
> (a2) So verstehe ich dies noch nicht. …
>
> (b1) Also, ich verstehe dies noch nicht. …
>
> (b2) Also verstehe ich dies noch nicht. …

Which ones are correct?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/usage-of-so-and-also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As a conjunction or as an adverb, *so* is sometimes translated as *so* in German. In your case, however, it's an interjection, which is used after a short pause; here to pick up the topic again in order to pose a further question.
   As a interjection it is always translated as *also* (which is never translated as *also* from German to English).
2. In German it's not that common to say *dies* and *jenes* as you would use *this* and *that* in English. You should simply say *das*.
3. As this is a normal main clause, the word order is still: subject (=Ich), predicate (=versteh nicht), object (=das/dies). Of course, *nicht* moves to the end of the sentence as you already did.

> Also, ich versteh' das noch nicht. Warum hast du das auf diese Art und Weise gemacht?

If you want to stress the object you can change the word order. You put the object in the first place and switch subject and verb:

> Also, *das* versteh ich nicht.

Answer (score 4):

My translations for

> "So, I still don't understand this. Why did you do it that way?"

are

> "Also, ich verstehe das immer noch nicht. Warum hast du das so
> gemacht?"
>
> "Also, das verstehe ich immer noch nicht. Warum hast du das so
> gemacht?"

My apologies for the "so" in the second sentence, it's not meant to muddy the waters. As Em1 said, you'd pick the second version to emphasize that a particular problem is hard; the first one expresses a personal lack of understanding.

However, I have known people start similar sentences with "So, ..." or "Na, ..." rather than "Also, ...". There are regional, personal, and situational preferences at play.

Answer (score 2):

(b2) is correct for „also“ with the meaning of “hence”. (b1) is nearer to your English sentence. (a1) would not be said at all, (a2) has the same meaning as „Ich verstehe das so noch nicht.“ That is not what you want.

Comment: Can’t agree with (a1) not being said at all, see the last paragraph of divby0’s answer.

Answer (score -3):

*Also* means *so* and it doesn't change the word order, however words such as *weil* and *wenn* do. E.g. *Also ich mache Karten*.

Comment: That's not generally true. In some cases, *also* can be used as an independent part of the sentence (and then needs to be surrounded by commas). Normally however, it does change the word order: _Also mache ich Karten_ (whatever that is supposed to mean).