# Use of 'so' as interjection at sentence start

Tags: word-choice

According to the top answer from [Word order with “so” and “also”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/word-order-with-so-and-also), "so" is never used at the start of a sentence as an interjection.

That said, in Pokemon Schwarze Edition, this is said at some point:

> So, dein Pokemon ist wieder putzmunter!

AFAIU, "so" should have been "also", with the sentence meaning "Well, your pokemon are lively again!". Is this correct?

Comment: I think @Em1 means that the English "so" when used as an interjection doesn't translate to "so". That doesn't mean that the German "so" can't be used as interjection. Examples like yours are very common but the English translation is something like "All right."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"So" is indeed never used in German in the sense of English "so" (therefore) at the beginning of the sentence, that is usually translated as "also". The "so" in your example sentence means something like "here" or "it's finished", and in that sense it can and is used at the beginning of a sentence. "Well" doesn't really represent the meaning.

Comment: Definitely it. Thanks! Just found Emanuel's excellent article on that as well - http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/meaning-german-so/

Answer (score 2):

Man kann im Deutschen einen Satz mit "so" beginnen, zB "So, jetzt tut es Dein Spielzeug wieder". Es drückt dann eine vorangegangene Änderung eines Zustands aus. Anderes Beispiel wäre, wenn ich meinem Sohn nach dem Händewaschen sage "So, jetzt kannst Du wieder spielen gehen".